# Pass MotionEvent between views

Tags: android

I have a dialog window with `ImageView`. When I'm touching image `Dialog` is dismissed, but user still pressing the screen. Problem is that this touch event isn't passed to window below my `Dialog` (for example an `Activity`).

Can I somehow pass this `MotionEvent` (with `ACTION_DOWN`) to `Activity` so it still be able to generate new motion events (with `ACTION_MOVE` and `ACTION_UP` accordingly)?

**EDIT**

What I'm trying to do exactly in my `Activity`:

```
//Sending touch event
MotionEvent ev = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis()+100, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 50, 50, 0);
getWindow().getDecorView().dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
```

and here is my `dispatchTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent`:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if(mDragging) {
        mMainFrame.onTouchEvent(ev); //I'm passing event to some view
        onTouchEvent(ev); //and then to my Activity
        return true;
    }

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the method `onTouchEvent` needs to return a boolean.

From the docs

True if the event was handled, false otherwise.

In case you have an underlying layer you might have to call super(boolean)